# jQuery: Dynamically generated anchor element cannot be selected

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am writing some code to generate anchor elements via Ajax call to the server. The list is generated successfully. But when i tried to select the anchor element by it's class, I retrieved nothing. Is there something wrong with my code? Any suggestions? I appreciate all your feedback. Thanks

here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  generate_link('somelink.php', '#link ul');

  $(".mylink").css("border","3px solid red"); //this is not works :-(

});   

function generate_link(method_url, target)
{

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: method_url,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
             var str='';
             for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                str = str + ('<li><a href="' + data[i]['anchor'] +'" class="mylink"></li>');
                   }
             $(target).html(str);
          } 
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that CSS is being applied when the page loads and not when you do your AJAX call, the CSS isn't being applied to the elements added with AJAX. Try moving the line where you set the border to 3px solid red to the `success` callback, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  generate_link('somelink.php', '#link ul');
});   

function generate_link(method_url, target)
{

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: method_url,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
             var str='';
             for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                str = str + ('<li><a href="' + data[i]['anchor'] +'" class="mylink"></li>');
                   }
             $(target).html(str);
             $(".mylink").css("border","3px solid red"); 
          } 
        });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @under5hell You won't ever see anything generated by JavaScript in the source. JavaScript manipulates the source after it loads, so to see the links'c ode you'll need to open Developer Tools (F12) or FireBug for Firefox. That should work though.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. The link is generated without css applied on it. I took a peek on the page source code via browsers view->source menu but the links is not there. How this could be? It showed up on the page but not in source code :-?

Comment: wow, sorry.. my bad. I made a mistake on last try. Now your solution is working :-) thanks

Comment: now I am facing another strange thing. I changed the code `$(".mylink").css("border","3px solid red");`. Replacing it, so it show an alert when it get clicked. And now the alert window shows up... instead it showed up three times. What could be wrong?

Comment: Its most likely because of the **FOR** loop. It probable go execute times. Making the alert show, 3 times.

Comment: @Shawn31313 No, I don't think the selection is in the `for` loop.

Comment: @under5hell Do you have your code online so I could see what is happening?

Comment: @Shawn31313 no, it's not. I put the selection outside the loop scope. Even if I put it in the loop, it should execute 20 times not three times because my data.length is 20.

Comment: @Nathan I don't have it online yet. I think i found the bug. Basically, my app is twitter client. I load the `generate_link()` function three times when the page loaded to refresh user,home, and mention timeline. So, when i clicked the link, the code is already executed three times. Do you have any advice how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @under5hell Hmm, I still don't see how it would cause an alert 3 times. Even if you do 3 `.click()` with an alert inside, it'll only alert once unless you put the alert 3 times. Or am I misunderstanding what you have for the code? Could you paste the code you're using into [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and then comment with the URL to it?

Comment: @Nathan i posted my code on Pastebin .. here's the http://pastebin.com/bUu1tgCA .. please check itu out. :-)

Comment: @Nathan what I am trying to accomplish with the script is simulating twitter timeline. At the first time the page loaded it should presenting the timeline. Then it should refresh the timeline every 60 seconds, each list item in the timeline contain a link for twitting. When the link get clicked it will show a form modal box. But now, it shows me the modal box three times. Any advice from you will be very valuable to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the time your code runs, the links are not present on the page.

Select the elements in the `success` callback of your `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line to the callback function

```
$(".mylink").css("border","3px solid red"); //this is not works :-(
```

Jquery is issuing the Ajax request, and then, not having received a response yet, instantly executes the line above. At that point, the links haven't been created yet.

So, your AJAX call should look like

```
function generate_link(method_url, target)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: method_url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
         var str='';
         for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            str = str + ('<li><a href="' + data[i]['anchor'] +'" class="mylink"></li>');
               }
         $(target).html(str);
         $(".mylink").css("border","3px solid red"); //added this here
      } 
    });
```

}